# How do I save a imageView setting?

Tags: java, android

I have a button to where you press it, it changes the picture inside an imageView. I would like to know how to save it in a setting after you press that button, so that when I reopen the app it will show the picture I previously selected.

This onClick is in my onCreate:

```
button31.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

This is my onActivityResult method:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            background2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to save data in Android. For your requirement I would suggest using the SharedPreference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//read Value:
prefs.getString("selImageUrl");

//writeValue:
prefs.edit.putString("selImageUrl", "yourImgageUrl");
```

see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html